# Is there any way to copy files to Appservice container over remote shell?

Tags: scp, azure-app-service-plans, azure-appservice, azure-app-service-envrmnt

We were able to successfully connect to the Appservice container using the remote shell using below az command.

```
az webapp create-remote-connection --subscription ******** --resource-group myrg -n mywebapp &
```

we were able succesfully ssh to the appservice container with the given port with root user and password.

```
ssh root@127.0.0.1 -p 359xx
```

But when we tried to copy files from local machine to  the container,its throwing permission denied.

```
scp -p 359XX myfile root@127.0.0.1:/tmp/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I succeeded with:

```bash
rsync -az --bwlimit=500 -e 'ssh -p <port> -c aes256-cbc' ./database.sql.tar.gz root@127.0.0.1:~/
```

The `--bwlimit` bandwidth limit argument was the success factor.

In my case I had to specify the cypher algorithm(`-c aes256-cbc`) but if you can ssh without then in the rsync command you don't need it as well.

Answer (score 0):

> But when we tried to copy files from local machine to the container, its throwing permission denied

When enough permissions are not granted to access (read/write) the data from the local host (remote) to a server, then the `permission denied` comes:

[image]

If you want to copy specific files, then check and give the permissions using this command: `chmod -R 777 filename` because `chmod -R 777` will gives all permissions to the root directory.

`ssh -i ./downloads/filename.pem azureuser@IP_Address`

Then copy the files using Secure Copy command `scp -p xxxx filepath/filename webserverusername@ipaddress`

Refer to one of the similar issues registered on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66492/scp-copy-over-ssh-doesnt-work-permission-denied-error-please) and many working solutions given by different authors.

**Note**: *Another reason is in few of the Corporate Systems, Secure Shells (SSH) is restricted to use so that the error comes like `permissions denied`, `TimedoutError`, `Internal server error`*.